# Dropdown in navbar not showing list of elements(Angular 6)

Tags: html, css, angular

I write navbar component in my Angular 6 app.

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">tekst</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">tekst</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

and .css file:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e8d625;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #090909;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #f7e525;
}

.active {
  background-color: #f7e525;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #77ffb7;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f7e525;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #80f987;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #80f987;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

but it's not working. 
When I use the mouse, dropdown does not display anything.. It's difficult to say but I use https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp .
Do not I have any libraries?

And other question. Will I be able to use  in dropdown later? Beacuse I use RoutingModule.

Very thanks for all answers.

EDIT:
add left navbar

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">info1</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info2</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info3</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info4</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *navbar is not working*? please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow: hidden` rule from `ul`, otherwise the dropdown won't be visible.

```css
ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #e8d625;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: #090909;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #f7e525;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #f7e525;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: #77ffb7;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
      margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #f7e525;
    }
    
    /* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #80f987;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    /* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #80f987;
    }
    
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    
    
    
    ul.side {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
.side li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">tekst</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">tekst</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>

<ul class="side">
  <li><a href="default.asp">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">info1</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info2</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info3</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">info4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks!
I have other question. When I actually have any component below, then dropdown show list of elements but under the below component. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you add some HTML to your original question to show what you mean?

Comment: I added left navbar menu. I have two component - top and left navbars. When I click on first dropdown, the list showing elements under component number 2. I would like to show this on front.

Comment: @Bartosz20188 I've updated the answer. Just make sure the navbar `ul` has a higher `z-index` than the sidebar. By the way, if this answer has solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green tick.

Comment: I already have a problem, so that the margin: 0, there is a white space bar on the left. How can I change this?

Comment: It depends what's causing the white space. Are you able to create a StackBlitz or jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?